# Progress bar while adding data from Userform

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want a progress bar while I add data from a userform.

When I click the add button the progress bar should run while the "adding data" code runs.
And finally I want to a message box to say the process is successful.

Code to add data from userform to Excel worksheet.

```vb
Private Sub cmbAddItem_Click()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ITEMS")
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sht.Range("ITEM_LIST").CurrentRegion
    
    LastRow = rng.End(xlDown).Row + 1
    
    With sht
        .Cells(LastRow, 3) = lblItemId
        .Cells(LastRow, 4) = txtItemname
        .Cells(LastRow, 5) = lblDate
        .Cells(LastRow, 6) = txtItemDes
        .Range("ITEM_LIST").Rows(rng.Rows.Count).Font.Name = "Franklin Gothic Book"
        .Range("ITEM_LIST").Rows(rng.Rows.Count).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    
    '--------------------------- load listbox or refresh listbox by class
    loaditemlist
    
    Call ItemCode ' update item code label for next item
    
    lblTotItem = Application.CountA(Range("ITEM_CODE")) ' To Refresh
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End sub
```

Comment: The answer I gave in this question should work.  Although looking at your code it looks like it should execute fast enough not to need a progress bar.  [How to display progress bar when userform is loading in VBA excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052415/how-to-display-progress-bar-when-userform-is-loading-in-vba-excel/31056031#31056031)

Comment: It gives me the error 402 "must close or hide topmost modal from first" ---------------ERR_HANDLE:
    Err.Clear
    ProgressBar.Hide

Comment: Yes, you'll need to set the `ShowModal` property of the main form to false.  It does mean the user can then click on the worksheet / other forms while the main form is active.  May not work for you in that case.  This MrExcel link may help: [How can I change a Modal Userform from Modal to Modeless at run time](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-can-i-change-a-modal-userform-from-modal-to-modeless-at-run-time.408356/)

Answer (score 0):

Create label in userform, change Name to "progressBar". Clear caption label1.. put whitespace (" " ).
You can look for website for further detailed description how to create more colorful  https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-progress-bar/

```
Sub yoursubroutine()
Userform.progressBar.Width=0

'When it will start reading your code width of label equals 0. Gradually, 'line by line you will add up as per you see it properly in ratios.

*your code*
Userform.progressBar.Width=30
Userform.progressBar.BackColor=vbBlue
*your code*
Userform.progressBar.Width=60
Userform.progressBar.BackColor=vbBlue
*your code*
Userform.progressBar.Width=85
Userform.progressBar.BackColor=vbBlue
*your code*
Userform.progressBar.Width=100
Userform.progressBar.BackColor=vbBlue

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.. but as i am new to this coding world... could you please help me by placing your codes between my work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).